# How to enable duplicate functionality on ACF Repeater

Tags: wordpress, advanced-custom-fields, acfpro, acf-gutenberg

I'm using ACF for building custom Wordpress configuration options (inside custom options pages, settings, CPTs, Gutenberg blocks etc), for more than 5 years. I know there's an option in repeater fields to duplicate rows, but how can I enable it? All times I need to duplicate a row, I need to "inspect" the row element and, manually, disable the `display:none;` rule in the duplicate row button.

So, I think it's disabled by default, and I need to "enable" it in some way. I can't find an option in the ACF configutation screen to enable it, and, since I started using ACF builder to improve fields management inside my themes, I'm not using the "normal" ACF configuration screen.

Can someone help me with this? How can I enable the duplicate row functionality in ACF repeater fields?

Comment: Can you share the admin screenshot with inspect element?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Try holding down shift when you hover the right toolbar (the column with add and remove row buttons) for ACF repeaters. That should toggle the "add row" with "duplicate row".

Comment: Lol, I'm using ACF since years daily and wasn't aware of this until now. Thank you!

Comment: 8 years using ACF and I've just realised this now haha :D Thanks